# Git "autosquash" without squashing?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history, git-squash

Any way to perform an "autosquash" without actually squshing the commits (i.e. just reorder commits marked with `--fixup` s.t. I can fix the merge conflicts prior to code review)?

Comment: If you need to reorder commits, won't `git rebase -i HEAD~N` work for you, where you just move the commits up and down?

Comment: @mnestorov Yes, but the point of using `fixup` and `autosquash` IS that I don't have to move the commits one-by-one myself.

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding :) looking at the documentation, would `--no-autosquash` be of any use?

Comment: IIRC rebase -i reorders and sets up squashs with autosquash. You could then change the squashs to commits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not (at least not out-of-the-box). You could run a simple substitute command vim to replace all "fixup" or "squash" lines in the rebase script with "pick" (the default, i.e. create a new commit):

```
%s/^fixup\|^squash/pick/
```

You might map that to a keyboard shortcut in vim or store it in a macro, so that you are able to run it more quickly.